# Webmin: Сборка deb-пакетов из git-репозитория

Tags: linux, debian

Требуется создать пакет со своим набором модулей.

Скачал [исходники](https://github.com/webmin/webmin). Однако не нашёл руководства как из них собрать желаемое.

Как собрать *deb*-пакет из исходников *webmin*-а?

Comment: универсальной инструкции «как собрать пакет из git-репозитория» не может существовать в принципе. а по поводу конкретно *webmin* — можете взять за основу исходники пакета из архивов *debian*-а. лет эдак десять назад он там был, пока не выкинули из-за проблем. // брать за основу те исходники пакета, которые публикуют разработчики *webmin*-а бесполезно — они некорректные и пакет с помощью них собрать невозможно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin речь конечно конкретно о webmin. И да, то что разработчики публикуют в Source не собираемо, так как нету debian/rules.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо за наводку, нашёл старый пакет https://archive.debian.net/source/sarge/webmin

Comment: дополнил ответ мини-инструкцией.

Comment: В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/754425/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-webmin/766778#766778) дал ссылку на подробную инструкцию

Comment: Инструкция не о данном вопросе

Answer (score 1):

универсальной инструкции «как собрать пакет из git-репозитория» не может существовать в принципе. а по поводу конкретно webmin — можете взять за основу исходники пакета из архивов *debian*-а. лет эдак десять назад он там был, пока не выкинули из-за проблем.

брать за основу те исходники пакета, которые публикуют разработчики webmin-а бесполезно — они некорректные и пакет с помощью них собрать невозможно — если скачать из [каталога с последней версией](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/files/webmin/1.791/) файлы с суффиксами `.tar.gz`, `.diff` и `.dsc`, то, выполнив в попытке распаковки получим лишь ошибку:

```
$ dpkg-source -x webmin*.dsc
...
dpkg-source: error: unrecognized file for a v1.0 source package: webmin-1.791.tar.gz
```

даже если вручную распаковать архив и наложить патчи:

```
$ tar -xf webmin*.tar.gz
$ ( cd webmin*/ && cat ../webmin*.diff | patch -p1 )
```

то получим в каталоге исходников, во-первых, некорректно названный каталог `DEBIAN` (должно быть `debian`), во-вторых, даже после переименования каталога и попытки сборки получим лишь кучу предупреждений о некорректном содержимом `debian/changelog` и закономерную ошибку:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l3): unrecognized line
...
dpkg-buildpackage: error: unable to determine source changed by
```

если даже исправить некорректныйй файл `debian/changelog`, то дальше последует ошибка про некорректность `debian/contrl` и т.д.

---

если же взять исходники из [архива *debian*](https://archive.debian.net/source/sarge/webmin), то они отлично распаковываются и пакеты благополучно собираются.

остаётся только обновить исходники самого *webmin*-а до актуальной версии, ориентируясь на [соответствующую часть руководства начинающего разработчика debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/update.ru.html).

---

**мини-инструкция по сборке webmin**

1. установите необходимые пакеты:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts
   ```
2. создайте каталог для сборки и сделайте его текущим. например, `~/src/webmin`:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/src/webmin
   $ cd ~/src/webmin
   ```
3. скачайте исходники старого debian-овского пакета и актуальные на данный момент исходники webmin-а:

   ```
   $ wget http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/webmin/webmin_1.180-3sarge1.dsc \
    http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/webmin/webmin_1.180.orig.tar.gz \
    http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/webmin/webmin_1.180-3sarge1.diff.gz \
    https://sourceforge.net/projects/webadmin/files/webmin/1.791/webmin-1.791.tar.gz
   ```
4. распакуйте исходники пакета:

   ```
   $ dpkg-source -x webmin_1.180-3sarge1.dsc
   ```
5. в каталоге `webmin-1.180` выполните `uupdate -v новая-версия ../архив-с-новой-версией`:

   ```
   $ ( cd webmin-1.180; uupdate -v 1.791 ../webmin-1.791.tar.gz )
   ```

   в выводе будут сообщения о неналожившихся патчах, что вполне естественно — сильно уж версии отличаются. придётся игнорировать.
6. в каталоге с новой версией выполните `dch` для обновления файла `debian/changelog`:

   ```
   $ ( cd webmin-1.791; dch )
   ```

   в открывшемся редакторе уберите лишние строки, если они будут добавлены, чтобы верхняя секция выглядела примерно так (последняя строка, понятно, будет у вас отличаться):

   ```
   webmin (1.791-1) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium

     * New upstream release

    -- пользователь <пользователь@хост>  Fri, 29 Apr 2016 16:50:59 +0000
   ```
7. в том же каталоге запустите сборку пакетов:

   ```
   $ ( cd webmin-1.791; dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc )
   ```

   если всё прошло удачно, то закончится вывод примерно такими строками:

   ```
   ...
   dh_builddeb
   dh_builddeb: Compatibility levels before 5 are deprecated (level 4 in use)
   dpkg-deb: building package `webmin' in `../webmin_1.791-1_all.deb'.
   dh_builddeb: Compatibility levels before 5 are deprecated (level 4 in use)
   dpkg-deb: building package `webmin-core' in `../webmin-core_1.791-1_all.deb'.
   dh_builddeb: Compatibility levels before 5 are deprecated (level 4 in use)
    dpkg-genchanges  >../webmin_1.791-1_amd64.changes
   dpkg-genchanges: including full source code in upload
    dpkg-source --after-build webmin-1.791
   dpkg-buildpackage: full upload (original source is included)
   ```
8. файлы лежат в `~/src/webmin`:

   ```
   webmin_1.791-1_all.deb
   webmin-core_1.791-1_all.deb
   ```

за работоспособность собранного *webmin-а*, конечно, не ручаюсь.