# не подключается к Webmin

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, сервер

Основная ось Win 10x64 гостевая через VMware Workstation Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 x32
Соединение Bridged что бы был доступ к интернету и была связь с основной ОС, далее на Ubuntu Server установил LAMP и Webmin, команда ifconfig в гостевой ОС показала 192.168.100.7, если из основной ОС зайти на http://192.168.100.7/ то открывается Apache а вот если зайти на http://192.168.100.7:10000/ то пишет Error - Document follows и предлагает перейти на адрес [https://svr1:10000/(при](https://svr1:10000/(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8) переходе пишет "Не удается получить доступ к сайту" ) "svr1" это имя гостевого сервера, если написать service webmin status показывает ON значит по идее сам Webmin работает, но почему тогда на него не заходит не по адресу localhost не по 192.168.100.7 не по 127.0.0.1 В iptables добавил порт вот так "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT" но все ровно не заходит в Webmin. Почему? и как зайти?

Comment: Разобрался в чем была проблема нужно было зайти на "httpS" ""https"://192.168.100.7:10000/"

Comment: На всякий случай оставлю перевод стать по [установке WebMin на CentOS](https://insidewebdev.com/servers/ustanovka-webmin-centos7/), мало ли пригодится кому также как мне сегодня.